# Can you... get it on... with anyone or just certain characters?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

In Dragon Age: Origins, is it possible to seduce anyone or are there only certain characters that each character is able to seduce?

I noticed that my female mage was able to start flirting with a female rogue, for example.  Are any of the NPC characters fair game or will the the dialogue just turn me down?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Female characters have romance options available with Alistair, Zevran, and Leliana.

Male Wardens trade in Allistair for Morrigan, and can also romance Zevran and Leliana.

Basically, the rogues swing both ways.

Comment: Under certain circumstances, you are also able to have a threesome/foursome with Isabela at The Pearl, though there is no cutscene for it.

Comment: This sounds like a great game, where can I get a copy?

Comment: @Fallen - Well, yes, but that's hardly a seduction, much less a romance.

Comment: Wait, so my female mage can't get in the sack with Morrigan? What a disappointment.